# Delete an ObjectId from an Array - MongoDB, Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to delete a 'category' document and it's ObjectId that is in an array inside the 'menu' Schema.
The 'menu' Schema looks like this :

```
categories: [
  {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: "Category",
  },
```

it holds the ObjectId i am trying to delete

This is the nodejs code from the controller I try to run :

```
    const deletedCat = await Category.findByIdAndRemove(catId, function (err) {
  if (err) console.error(err)
})
const updateMenu = await Menu.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: menuId },
  { $pull: { categories: { _id: new ObjectId(catId) } } },
  { new: true }
)
```

the $pull doesn't change the DB and the ObjectId is still in the Array.

I also tried without the " new ObjectId "

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so i just got it to work.
The answer is simple, just use the ObjectId as a value of the key in the Array (name of the array)

```
const updateMenu = await Menu.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: menuId },
  { $pull: { categories: ObjectId(catId) } },
  { new: true }
)
```

Comment: Hey, I wondering if you had any issues with this later down the line. I'm getting ObjectId is not defined. Possibly something changed with Mongoose since 2020? I noticed that your model defines the  field slightly different, as the docs I've seen show to defined the field as: fieldArray: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'OtherModel'}]. Even when adjusting for that I get schema is not defined. Was there a step you had to do to define ObjectId in the controller making the delete?